# How can I connect to a Server using a SSL for the Hostname Through a NAT

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, nat

I have a server configured with a hostname inside my LAN, say `https://myserver/`. I need to grant access to this server to a client through a VPN, with a NATed IP, let's say `10.0.1.101`, and to whom I handed a certificate to validate the connection.

If I understand correctly, the SSL certificate will be marked as invalid if he tries to access the server through the IP. But what if I ask the client to assign a hostname to the IP so that he accesses `https://10.0.1.101/` through `https://myserver/`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Whoever provides DNS for the VPN (whoever is running the VPN server) would need to provide the hostname.

So if you add a DNS A record that says myserver resolves to 10.0.1.101 and your VPN server assigns your DNS server in DHCP responses then it should be ok.

You should really use a Fully Qualified Domain Name instead of a hostname to prevent resolution problems.